# Taking Photo in Android OnActivityResult not responding

Tags: android, fragment, android-camera-intent

**[ANSWER IS HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952454/4491661)**

Thanks guys for all the help.

---

I've got a `Fragment` with code that allows user to take a photo. After photo gets taken other actions take place. My problem is that these other actions don't get initiated.

Here's the code. I never receive the "Photo Taken" message in LogCat.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE) {
        if(resultCode ==  Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Log.i("Debug", "Photo Taken");

        }

    }
}
```

I tried changing `Activity.RESULT_OK` to `MainActivity.this`, `MainActivity` and `getActivity()`, but no use.

Take photo code:

```
 centCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             count++;
            file = dir+count+".jpg";
            currentPhotoString = file;
            File newfile = new File(file);
            try {
                newfile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {}       

            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);


            someMethod();

           Handler handler = new Handler();
          handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
          @Override
                public void run(){
           sideCamera.setEnabled(true);
             sideCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



       centCamera.setEnabled(false);
       centCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
         }, 500);


        }
    });
```

Comment: is this method written in fragment ?

Comment: Instead of `Log.i` I've got a call to `private void` inside this Fragment. Moving it is not an option. Plus `onActivityResult` should work in Fragment

Comment: please show take photo code

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Is MainActivity overriding onActivityResult?

Comment: no, it's not doing that

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> I never receive the "Photo Taken" message in LogCat.

Have you made any changes to your Activity's `onActivityResult` method?This might be because it would ultimately call `onActivityResult` of your `Activity` first. and as you did not pass the same callback to your `Fragment` 's `onActivityResult` you are not getting your callback in your `Fragment`

So, do something like below in your activity's `onActivityResult`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(frag_yourfrag!=null){
    frag_yourfrag.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
     }
}
```

where `frag_yourfrag` is referring to your instance of Fragment class you call from Activity

Comment: placing this in Activity, forces me to make frag's onActivityResult static. Then the onAcRes in fragment gives an error, which can be fixed only by making it non-static. Closed loop of sorts

Comment: Initially I did not have onActivityResult in MainActivity.java

Comment: inside Activity you need to call onActivityResult through INSTANCE OF FRAGMENT not Directly through Class. I guess you need to work on your java to resolve this kind of usual issues No worries I hope it helps now :)

Comment: what do you mean "through instance of fragment"?

Comment: How you are instantiating your fragment from your acitivity? you will need to save the instance in your activity. and use the same in your onActivityResult

Comment: It's actually Activity > Fragment (ViewPager) > Fragment (with photo code)

Answer (score 0):

Try by overriding `onActivityResult` in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

After that, the result should be passed to your fragment which holds the instance of `ViewPager`.

If you want the result in one of `ViewPager`'s fragment then in `Fragment` which holds the `ViewPager` do this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    List<Fragment> fragments = getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```